# how to handle a exception in java

Tags: java, exception

So I am using HtmlUnit, and the method's signature looks like:

```
public HtmlAnchor getAnchorByText(String text)
                           throws ElementNotFoundException
```

So this means, the call to this method won't just return null, but it will throw an exception.

(I find this a pain!!, in c# methods usually just return a null if not found, way easier unless I am missing something??)

So I HAVE to wrap this call in an exception if I don't want my application to crash right?

How do I do this in Java?

reference: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html

Comment: Don't forget that sometimes null is a valid return value so you can't always use it to signify a problem. Or there may be more than one thing that can go wrong so returning null isn't enough to tell you what the problem is. I guess I'm trying to say you'll be happier if you can understand how exceptions are meant to be used rather than seeing them as a hoop that must be jumped through.

Comment: Also note that just because it can be thrown (the "throws" clause just states the possibility of the exception being thrown) does not mean it *will* be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bear in mind that [`ElementNotFoundException`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/ElementNotFoundException.html) is *not* a checked exception so you could ignore it. But if the element not being there is a valid case that you don't want an exception thrown in then yes you will have to wrap the code in a try-catch block and deal with it.

I too find this kind of flow-control-by-exceptions painful. The basic construct you want is:

```
HtmlAnchor anchor = null;
try {
  htmlAnchor = getAnchorByText(text);
} catch (ElementNotFoundException) {
  // do nothing
}
```

If you find yourself writing this sequence a lot then wrap it in a helper method:

```
public static HtmlAnchor myFindAnchor(String text) {
  try {
    return getAnchorByText(text);
  } catch (ElementNotFoundException) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

and call that instead of littering your code with spurious try-catch blocks.

Answer (score 1):

-- Edit:

See cletus' answer; I assumed it was a checked exception because of the OPs description.

-- Old answer:

You just put a try/catch around it (or re-throw it from *your* method).

They are called "checked" exceptions, in Java, and are generally considered a mistake :) (but this is not really worth debating here).

```
try {
    getAnchorByText(,,,)
} catch (ElementNotFoundException enfe) {
    ///
}
```

or the throws:

```
public void myFoo (...) throws ElementNotFoundException
```

The idea is that you should not pass exceptions up to places that can't deal with them though (or at least, wrap it in something they *can* deal with). You try and constrain exceptions to varying 'levels' within your app.

Comment: Because only if it's checked do you need to handle it specifically, which is what he's complaining about.

Comment: I think there's some valid uses for checked exceptions, but yeah, they are generally overused.

Comment: notnoop: Please see my revised edit. There is absolutely no point continuing this discussion.

Comment: Thanks!  Just noticed the change.  Grr... I would love to give your your 2 points back ;-).

Comment: No worries :) Probably I should actually check the links before I answer, sorry if I seemed rude :)